# "Имеет место быть"

Tags: грамотная-речь

И еще вопрос. Насколько грамотным является выражение "имеет место быть"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**С "Грамоты"**
Вопрос
**Как правильно: имеет место быть или имеет место?**

Согласно словарям есть два выражения иметь место и имеет быть. Иметь место - быть налицо, наличествовать (книжное), это буквальный перевод французского выражения avoir lieu: имеют место следующие недостатки. Имеет быть - произойдет: заседание имеет быть. Неправильное выражение имеет место быть – результат контаминации двух названных выражений. Оба выражения – традиционно книжные и официально-деловые. При употреблении в иных стилях придают канцелярский оттенок контексту.
**Правильно: иметь место, имеет место и имеет быть** .  **Неправильно: имеет место быть.**

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем согласен. По моему скромному мнению и опыту, это выражение является описанием  факта регистрации определенного явления или процеса. "Имеет место быть" — наблюдение.

Answer (score 0):

Здеь, как мне кажется, мы сталкиваемся с ситуацией, когда живое развитие языка попирает правила. Как справедливо отметил в своём ответе пользователь Ларf, указанное выражение не соответствует словарной норме. Невзирая на это, оно уже более или менее прижилось в устной речи. С учётом указанной `неправильности' (или, скажем, некнижности), это выражение нередко несет в себе элемент сарказма. Последний раз я услышал его в диалоге с коллегой:
-- Вам не кажется, что этот аспирант полный мудак?
-- Имеет место быть.